# Upgrading Ubuntu Based distro without losing everything

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, zorin

I use Zorin OS 8. I have previously used Ubuntu and Know that to upgrade Ubuntu versions you can use the "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" command. I was wondering if that same command would work the same on Ubuntu based distros as it would on generic Ubuntu? Would I need to download a clean install of the next Zorin OS to have the latest and greatest? Thanks.

Comment: do-release-upgrade is the command for ubuntu. I can't say anything for Zorin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Zorin OS, but if it's Ubuntu-based (actually, Debian based), apt is surely installed. If it is, it works the same way in every distribution you can find !